# ElasticSearch creates unnecessary index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash to parse some data and feed it to ElasticSearch and it works fine except that ElasticSearch creates an index too much that I would like to avoid.

My Logstash configuration looks like this:

```
filter {
    date {
        locale => "en"
        match => [ "log_timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss +0100" ]
        timezone => "UTC" 
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["0.0.0.0:9200"]
        index => "index-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
    }
}
```

And it does indeed create an index for my data using the dates in the data.

So if I process data from 2016-01-14 today (2016-01-20) I get 2 indexes in my elasticSearch directory: **index-2016-01-14** and **index-2016-01-20**.

And I don't really want to have '**index-2016-01-20**', I only want the one for my data, in my case '**index-2016-01-14**'.

I hope I made myself a bit clear :)

Sample input data:

```
[14/Jan/2016:00:00:00 +0100]|bla|ip|...|200|0|0|
[14/Jan/2016:02:00:00 +0100]|cla|ip|...|200|0|0|
[14/Jan/2016:05:00:00 +0100]|dla|ip|...|200|0|0|
```

Comment: The index name creation is based on the value of the `@timestamp` field. Can you show some sample lines/events that get indexed?

Comment: Added some dample data. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you also show a sample document that lands into the `index-2016-01-20` index and how the corresponding log line looked?

Comment: I don't have those anymore, but if I remember correctly it was just some default logstash fields with current timestamp.

Comment: Ok, can you show how you grok your log lines? It might well be that the first date field is not being grokked properly. `index-2016-01-14` might have been created when you ran logstash on that day, and `index-2016-01-20` when you ran it today. This should be visible in the Elasticsearch log itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you browse the "bad" index, you'll see events with today's date.  This is due to a bad date{} filter, which is not resetting @timestamp, so today's value is used.

Comment: Where is this bad date{} filter? Logstash config or in my logstash grok?

Comment: Can you find a @timestamp value from one of the documents in the "bad" index?  Can you find the original message that logstash received?